# Can I use immutable identifiers in office.js.api?

Tags: email, microsoft-graph-api, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Can I use immutable identifiers [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-immutable-id) from GRAPH API in `office.js.api`?
Somehow setting needed header to make identificatory not changeable if email is switched from Draft to Sent folder for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Immutable IDs do not work with any office.js apis. The only itemID available is the EWSId via Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId. However, as you noted the EWSId will change if the item switches folders.

You may be able to use Graph/REST to translate the EWSId into immutable: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-translateexchangeids?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

But Office.js inputs/outputs are always EWSId's in the function.